# Potential leak of an object - NSData

Tags: xcode, memory-leaks, static-analysis

When I Analyze a class I'm working on this line of code:

```
    myObject.myImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:myObject.thumbnailUrlString]];
```

has a warning `Potential leak of an object`.

Any idea why and how you fix it?

==== Note

If I try and separate this line out I get additional errors, e.g.

```
NSData *myImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:myObject.thumbnailUrlString]]; // 1. Method returns an Objective-C object with a +0 retain count
myObject.myImageData = myImageData;
[myImageData release]; // 2. Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have ARC turned on. You almost certainly should turn on ARC so that the system will handle all of this for you.

That said, this is a basic manual memory management error, and the analyzer is telling you so.

```
myObject.myImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:myObject.thumbnailUrlString]];
```

This leaks the `NSURL` you created with `+alloc`. You need to call `release` on it at some point, but you no longer have a pointer to it. The usual way to fix this is with an autoreleased `NSURL`:

```
myObject.myImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myObject.thumbnailUrlString]];
```

But the much better way to fix it is to turn on ARC.

Your attempt at fixing it releases the wrong object. You don't own `myImageData`. You didn't create it with `alloc`, `new`, or `copy`, and you didn't call `retain` on it. The analyzer is warning you that you're incorrectly releasing it.